# unwanted vertical spacing in supertabular with babel

Tags: spacing, babel, supertabular

I have a question regarding supertabular and babel. Whenever I'm using different language specifications inside a cell, there is a slight vertical space, which is not there when there is no language specification. I imagine something must be missing somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Supertabular is needed because the document I'm working on is about 30 pages long. Default language is French, but I have to include other languages in the cells.

When there is no language specification, the problem doesn't appear. I've put some exclamation points to show that the French spacing is effective, both as default and when specified (which is all but normal), to show that babel is working correctly at least for that.

[image: This is the output of the code shown below]

```
%!TeX - program = pdflatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,margin=2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{7.5cm}<{\raggedright}|p{7.5cm}|}

\hline
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
This is marked as English!
\end{otherlanguage}
&
Ceci n'est pas marqué!
\\
\hline

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
And again!
\end{otherlanguage}
&
Et encore!
\\
\hline
This time it isn't marked!
&
\begin{otherlanguage}{frenchb}
Cette fois-ci c'est marqué!
\end{otherlanguage}
\\
\hline

\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for all comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `supertabular`; here's a minimal example with a workaround:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
This is marked as English!
\end{otherlanguage}\\
\hline
\leavevmode\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
This is marked as English!
\end{otherlanguage}\\
\hline
Not marked\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem is that `\begin{otherlanguage}` places a *whatsit* for marking a point where to write an annotation in the `.aux` file. This happens at an unfortunate time when it's the first object in a `p` cell.

However, it makes probably more sense to use the `otherlanguage*` environment, in such a case. With

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
\hline
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
This is marked as English!
\end{otherlanguage*}\\
\hline
Not marked\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

the output is correct:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I figured it was something of the kind. Thanks for the workaround.